# Nginx rewrite for specific dir

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have to admit I am completely new to WebServers and now try to figure out how to configure my nginx (for home-purpose). I have already running a web-service rutorrent on my nginx with the default structure. Now I wanna change the dir structure into:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/        (should contain the default-config)
/usr/share/nginx/rtorr_dir/   (should contain the rutorrent-content)
```

My aim is: On my browser I wanna enter `192.168.0.2/rutorrent` and this should automatically access on the `rtorr_dir`. I tried the following:

```
server {
        listen *:80;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log info;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    auth_basic      "ruser";
    auth_basic_user_file    /etc/users.htpasswd;

        location /rutorrent {
          rewrite /rutorrent/(.*) /$1 break;
          root /usr/share/nginx/rtorr_dir;
          index index.php index.html;
        }

        location /RPC1 {
          include /etc/nginx/scgi_params;
          scgi_pass backend2;
        }
        location ~  \.php$ {
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
          fastcgi_pass   backend;
        ....
```

I tried as well `location /` and other variations but obviously not the proper ones :(. So my question would be

- How to set up the rewrite properly?
- What is the change, when the root has already some part of the url included? (e.g. rtorr_dir)
- Do I need to change for the other locations as well something, or is this taken automatically for the underlying files (i.e. php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alias` directive in your use case. Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

So,

```
location /rutorrent {
  alias /usr/share/nginx/rtorr_dir;
}
```

Should work. You may still need `index` and directives.

> Do I need to change for the other locations as well something, or is
>   this taken automatically for the underlying files (i.e. php)?

Since, you use multiple locations, I'd recommend using `location ~* \.php$ {` on each of those locations. For example...

```
location /rutorrent {
  alias /usr/share/nginx/rtorr_dir;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

  location ~* \.php$ {
    # directives to process PHP
  }
}

location /another_random_location {
  alias /usr/share/nginx/another_random_directory;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

  location ~* \.php$ {
    # directives to process PHP
  }
}
```

If you keep a PHP location block **alongside** other location blocks, then that PHP block would only get it's path from the `root` directive set for the `server` block. The safest way is to include the PHP location block on each location that needs to process PHP.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for the hint. Especially thx for the complete sample, cause only the first half wouldn't have made it. And also thx for the PHP tip. You made my day :)